# PHP - GD fails on certain files only why?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

I am using following sample code to resize the given Image, However some images (only very few handful set of photos but considerable number of times) it fails and return black jpeg **without any errors in the functions**.

HOWEVER if i open that image in Photoshop and save it again **AS IT IS** as a JPEG (same file type) then it seems to be working. it correctly resize the new saved image.

I am wondering whats wrong with the original ? because original file seems be in correct format and can be opened even in windows photo viewer.

please note there is no issues with

1. file not existing
2. file types...etc (extension is jpeg)
3. sorry i cant post a sample photo due to privacy reasons here.
4. latest GD Library is installed and working fine for other images
5. **Actually i found out its "$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);" that fails it returns false for the failed images and others it returned "resource(5) of type (gd) " when i do "var_dump($image);"**

further debuging found me following error

**`Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG`**

***ANY SOLUTIONS OR REASONS FOR THIS ?***

Code i use to resize is below.

```
<?php

$thumb=resizeImage('20160612_123658_web.jpg',500,500);
// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
// Output
imagejpeg($thumb);

/**
* Resize an image and keep the proportions
* @author Allison Beckwith <allison@planetargon.com>
* @param string $filename
* @param integer $max_width
* @param integer $max_height
* @return image
*/
function resizeImage($filename, $max_width, $max_height)
{
    list($orig_width, $orig_height) = getimagesize($filename);

    $width = $orig_width;
    $height = $orig_height;

    # taller
    if ($height > $max_height) {
        $width = ($max_height / $height) * $width;
        $height = $max_height;
    }

    # wider
    if ($width > $max_width) {
        $height = ($max_width / $width) * $height;
        $width = $max_width;
    }

    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                     $width, $height, $orig_width, $orig_height);

    return $image_p;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935560/resizing-with-gd-outputs-black-images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935560/resizing-with-gd-outputs-black-images)

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH this is not a duplicate of that questions, as this only fails for certain images, answers given that question is not valid here

Comment: "Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG". It seems that this error is popular across the web it affects various programs.

Comment: Error messages make great search queries ~ https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/21873. Basically, `ini_set ('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);`

Comment: @Phil i tried that option but didn't work.it just hides the error messages image is still blank for no reason

Comment: Hmm, I had a feeling that might happen. Looks like you'll need to fix your JPEG images first. Saying there's *"no reason"* is wrong. Your images aren't valid as far as libjpeg is concerned

Comment: @Phil thats not a option either for me.because users upload these images as i said in windows..etc they are perfectly fine with no errors... if i produce a error file is no valid they will hit back at me whats wrong ?

Comment: You could try using another image processing library such as [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.imagick.php)

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for a picture taken with a phone (S5), not systematically, when running imagemagick's convert.exe.

The problem ceased after I cleaned the offending images with IrfanView lossless JPEG plugin (shortcut "J"), option "None (can be used for optimizing and cleaning)". Then using convert.exe did not result in any warnings.

So this is probably a non-compliance problem with the image metadata. For me it did not cause the black image problem quoted. Fixing the source JPEG file seems to be the way forward.